# Testing multiple hypotheses simultaneously

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, multiple-comparisons

Let $X_{ij}$ be data modeled by$X_{ij} \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim}N(\theta_j,\sigma_j^2), i=1,2,...,50, j=1,2,...,10$. We test $H_{0j}:\theta_j=0 $ against $H_{1j} : \theta_j\neq0$ for $j=1,2,...,10$ at a 
level of $\alpha=0.05$. Generate $X_{ij}$ and test the hypothesis, replicate $1000$ times to get the familywise error rate.

I am trying to use R to implement my solution.
From my understanding our sample size will be $50$. So we can get the values like so:

```
r.norm <- rnorm(50)
```

We want to find the Type-I error (where $H_0$ is true but we reject the null hypothesis). I wrote the below to count how many time we have a false rejection. But that seems incorrect, because our mean will not be equal to $0$, although that is out null hypothesis. Is my logic to calculate FWER correct?

```
FWER.count <- 0

for(i in 1:1000) {  
    for(j in 1:10) {
        r.norm <- rnorm(50)
        if(mean(r.norm) != 0) {
            if(t.test(r.norm)$p.value <= 0.05) {
                FWER.count <- FWER.count + 1;
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

FWER <- FWER.count/1000
```

Edit: Update FWER to have seperate variable for count and the probability. Also added a break to the loop, since we only need to know when one nulls in a group is falsely classified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This my translation of your code snippet.

If the mean of the sample has a mean of zero (it matches the family mean). A t-test is performed. If the p value is less than or equal to $ \alpha $, increment FWER. However, sample mean would only get tested if it matched the mean from the family exactly. The p-values would be 1. The null hypothesis would never get rejected.

*Note*

FWER would need to be divided by n, to make it a probability. The FWER is the probability of making even one type I error.

To make your code check sample means against the family where the sample mean does not equal zero, then this line.

```
if(mean(r.norm) == 0)
```

Should be this.

```
if(mean(r.norm) != 0)
```

Why because with a small sample size, I highly doubt the mean would ever be zero. I ran a small test to check.

```
sapply(rep(50,10), function(x) mean(rnorm(x)))
[1] -0.007272193  0.101159429  0.001891395 -0.138410041 -0.083892761  0.124589734 -0.057765727  0.240548953 -0.072762234 -0.193889501
```

It gets close, but never zero exactly.

You probably don't even need that first if statement, the mean would rarely be zero and the t-test if statement would ignore any mean that was close to zero.

Comment: I agree that for such a small size it will almost never be equal to zero, but I thought for a type-I error the null had to be true by definition. Yes, I am aware that I need to divide FWER by $n$ to get the probability, I just didn't include it in my code, will update the original post.

Comment: Ah I see. It is my understanding that one accepts null as true (p-value greater than or equal to $ \alpha $) or rejects null as true (p-value less than $ \alpha $). In this case the t-test determines if the null is accepted or rejected based on the significance level chosen. If you look at the wikipedia for [FWER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familywise_error_rate) it shows declared significant or declared non-signifiant. These would directly relate back to the t-test p-value results. Hope this helps!

Comment: Looking at the table on wiki, I am trying to find $V$. The top row "Null hypothesis is True" we check if the group mean is zero or not, and the significance is based on the $\alpha$ level? When I run my code the result seems to make sense, if I add more groups I get more false positives. So I think it works now.